# Style ngx-bootstrap tooltip arrow BORDER to take the shape of the arrow

Tags: css, angular, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

Currently, I am facing this issue with the ngx-bootstrap tooltip, arrow to give the border in its shape, I tried multiple solutions but got at max this far.
I have attached 2 images, first is the one I have achieved so far, second is what I want.
[image][image]

I am trying to achieve the second image, the below is the CSS of what I wrote till now.

```
.customClass .tooltip-inner {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
}

.customClass .arrow::before {
  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border to the arrow */
  background-color: #fff; /* Customize the arrow background color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to inspect the element even having a debugger after setTimeout on Hover, but I found out I was doing it in the wrong way. You can use the below CSS to achieve the  expected output.

```css
.customClass {
  --bs-tooltip-bg: red !important;
  position: relative;
}

.customClass .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  bottom: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.customClass .tooltip-inner::before,
.customClass .tooltip-inner::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 0.8rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.8rem solid transparent;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.8rem;
}

.customClass .tooltip-inner::before {
  border-top: 0.8rem solid #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

/* The white fill of the triangle */
.customClass .tooltip-inner::after {
  border-top: 0.8rem solid red;
  margin-top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.customClass .arrow {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please check your code snippet as its not working